# How to break a series of git commits into patches for submission to another project

Tags: git, patch

So I've been bashing away at my favorite open source project for quite some time, and It's time for submitting issues with patches back. I have to regroup my commits more or less fully, and hopefully extract some pieces of code that can function as distinct patches to avoid [code bombing](http://darkforge.blogspot.com/2010/02/code-bomb-or-newbie-with-big-ideas.html). Currently I usually do something like this:

1. rebase/squash everything to one commit since the old ones often don't make sense as patches
2. undo that commit
3. start adding stuff that I think fits to one commit, using add/add -i
4. commit
5. stash the rest
6. test that commit
7. re-apply the stash and start from 3 until all is accounted for

It works, but is there a better way ?

Comment: It sounds like you've come up with a pretty good method - essentially every step is a distinct concept, so I can't see you being able to eliminate any of them. (You might want to use `add -p` sometimes though.) What are you trying to do better?

Answer (score 2):

If current (unsquashed) commits has no relation to the patches you want to get, just keep doing according to your scheme.

Personally I would create "for-upstream" branch and cherry-pick some commits there (and split or edit them if needed), but this needs similar resources like using your way.

Comment: Well some commits have good relationship to the future patches, but I invariably tend to accumulate related changes in later commits. And I also often pollute these commits with other changes.